# Light weight alternatives to Teamviewer on Raspberry, Android type devices & Tiny linux distros?

Tags: gratis, android, linux, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi

### Little bit about TeamViewer & how it operates

> **What is the difference between TeamViewer and VNC?**
>
> With numerous modules and features, TeamViewer goes far beyond the
>   functionality of ordinary VNC solutions.
>
> The main difference is that TeamViewer **works without port forwarding**
>   and **configurations on firewalls and proxy servers**. Configurations with
>   TeamViewer are not necessary no matter if you need a *solution* for
>   **remote support, remote control, remote access**, or online meetings.
>
> TeamViewer allows you to focus on the task at hand.

As written [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18550/3342):
[Open-source solutions to make Linux desktop easily accesible remotely from Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18541/open-source-solutions-to-make-linux-desktop-easily-accesible-remotely-from-windo?rq=1)

> - Route through your firewall (without setting up port forwarding)
> - Doesn't require tinkering

**How does TeamViewer auto configure & bypass?**

- [SU: How exactly does a remote program like Team Viewer work?](https://superuser.com/questions/661749/how-exactly-does-a-remote-program-like-team-viewer-work)
- [SO: How does teamviewer find my computer even if my comp. behind of the firewall and firewall isn't configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776971/how-does-teamviewer-find-my-computer-even-if-my-comp-behind-of-the-firewall-and)
- [SF: How does TeamViewer get through my firewall even though I set it to “No incoming connections”? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/696674/how-does-teamviewer-get-through-my-firewall-even-though-i-set-it-to-no-incoming)
- [Security: How does Team Viewer establish a Remote Desktop Connection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/how-does-team-viewer-establish-a-remote-desktop-connection)

---

### Favorite TeamViewer alternative on Windows: Remote Utlities

- Alternatives work on Windows but I especially like & currently use "[Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com/)".
- It not only has access via the Client, but can also facilitate an RDP connection over the Internet (without needing to know IP/ configure things for RDP)

https://www.remoteutilities.com/product/features/remote-access.php

> **RDP-over-ID**
>
> Use Remote Utilities as transport [to start an RDP session over the Internet](https://www.remoteutilities.com/support/docs/rdp-over-id/) when the remote PC is not accessible directly by an IP address.

https://www.remoteutilities.com/support/docs/rdp-over-id/

> **RDP-over-ID**
>
> The RDP-over-ID feature allows you to connect to a remote computer
>   over the Internet using the RDP protocol **even when the remote computer is not directly accessible due to a firewall**. Instead, an **Internet ID connection is used as an encrypted “tunnel”** to facilitate the RDP connection.
>
> This feature is invoked automatically when you try to connect in the
>   RDP mode to a remote PC using its "Internet ID" instead of the IP
>   address.

---

Which means, I'm looking to find alternatives that exist, if any?

- I'd be open to something like RU that helps find the Remote Machine and facilitates an RDP connection (which would normally need and IP & Firewall bypass) instead of using its own.

  - Since, apparently xRDP can work on RPi (ref:)
- But I'm hard pressed to find anything other than VNC applications on tiny RPi/  Linux/ boxes.
- Prefer, Free or Freemium (e.g. N machines free) options that I use on Windows.

PS: Features and requirements & how these apps work have been marked in bold.

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) is cross platform(Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, IOS), does not require port forwarding or any changes to the firewall. You can easily connect to other computers with an access code, or set up a code for your computers to connect while you are away.

Comment: Im familiar with Chrome RD, but wonder if it can be run on an RPi ? Would like something that does not need for the user/ me to need to manually find the IP Address etc. Auto configuring from the Host - RPi?

Comment: I have never used it on a RPi but I have my laptop at home configured to allow me to connect from work just by clicking it and then entering a verification PIN.

Comment: Chrome Remore Desktop requires Chrome and that is the pitfall. I don't want to use dinosaur in order to get his single claw.

Answer (score 1):

[Anydesk](https://anydesk.com/platforms/raspberry-pi) was created by ex-employess from TeamViewer. It works about the same way. On my tests, it was a bit faster than TeamViewer. Also, they have a special version for RPi.

Anydesk is also free for personal use as the state on their website.

> AnyDesk is free for the occasional private use. Take the opportunity
>   to use “AnyDesk Free” to convince yourself of AnyDesk’s superior
>   performance! There are no hidden fees or obligations. Downloading
>   AnyDesk will get you started.
>   https://anydesk.com/order

They have clients for the following OSes:
Windows / macOS / Linux / FreeBSD / Android / iOS / Raspberry Pi
[image]

Comment: Is it Gratis for personal use with RPi?

Comment: @AlexS Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer to reflect your question.